# Trying to open a tab and scroll to the pane in jquery needs two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button at the top of my page labeled "ask a question", and some Bootstrap tabs below. I want to open the tab & scroll to it on the click of the button. So far, It needs two clicks to perform the action. The first click opens the tab, the second click scrolls. How can I combine the actions?

I tried this in Vanilla JS but Wordpress / Woocommerce was giving me issues so I needed Jquery.

Here's a Codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/OJWYMjP)

### Jquery

```
if ("#ask-question-button" && "#product-tab-QA_tab") {
    $("#ask-question-button").click(function () {
        $("#product-pane-QA_tab").get(0).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
        $("#product-tab-QA_tab").tab("show");
    });
}
```

### Edit:

This fixes the problem, but I'm curious why? Why not perform two actions in one function?

```
if ("#ask-question-button" && "#product-tab-QA_tab") {
    $("#ask-question-button").click(function () {
        $("#product-pane-QA_tab").get(0).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    });
        $("#product-tab-QA_tab").tab("show"); // One line moved down
}
```

Comment: switch `$("#product-pane-QA_tab").get(0).scrollIntoView` to `$("#v-pills-tabContent").get(0).scrollIntoView`?

Comment: `if ("#ask-question-button" && "#product-tab-QA_tab")`  is probably not doing what you expect, it will always be true as you're just asking the engine whether those **strings** are non-empty, which they always will be.

Comment: Ah good point. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with JQuery anymore, so hopefully someone will give you a better answer. you should probably call `.tab("show")` first, and then call the scroll. I'm not sure why the show seems to take a few cycles to complete, but it does, so adding a timeout gives you a buffer that allows for the tab to finish showing before you scroll.

```
if ("#ask-question-button" && "#product-tab-QA_tab") {
    $("#ask-question-button").click(function () {
        $("#product-tab-QA_tab").tab("show");
        setTimeout(() => 
        $("#product-pane-QA_tab").get(0).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" }), 200)
    });
}
```

Comment: @Sackadelic I'm not sure if you can "unmark" an answer, but you might be better off waiting for another answer. There's almost certainly a cleaner way to do this without the timeout using pure JQuery.